# How to edit line on file

Tags: java, android, file, text

This is my code:

```
public class FileReplace {
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line = null;

    public void  doIt() {
        try {
            File f1 = new File("d:/new folder/t1.htm");
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(f1);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.contains("java"))
                    line = line.replace("java", " ");
                lines.add(line);
            }
            fr.close();
            br.close();

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f1);
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            for(String s : lines)
                 out.write(s);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        FileReplace fr = new FileReplace();
        fr.doIt();
    }
}
```

and I have this text:

javascript_js
java_swing
java_fx
kotlin
python

I wanna edit `java_fx` to `java`. My code is deleting all content and write `java_fx`, how do I edit `java_fx` without erasing all content in file?

Comment: To my knowledge, the short answer is you cannot. You can read each line and modify the ones you want, but you have to write each line out again to the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f1, true);
```

Add true parameter to FileWriter constructor, this will avoid to rewriting content.

Comment: This is edit file, and append replacing text in end, but not edit java_fx to java

Comment: I tested your code and worked well. However in if(line.contains("java")) this will be "java_fx" not "java", because you want to replace java_fx to java. Also in my opinon you can't edit file without deleting all content, you must find word which you want to replace then write somewhere (you added to List<> collection) and write all content to file. Your code is right.